# Java :Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, classpath

Main class:

```
package org.example;

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
   }
}
```

is located at project\src\main\java\org\example\Main.java

I go over project\src\main\java\ directory and apply:

```
java org.example.Main
```

And get: Could not find or load main class org.example.Main

I tried also:

```
java -classpath org/example Main
```

And:

```
java -classpath ../../../ org/example/Main
```

But with the same result.
I'm using gradle for build.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command `java org.example.Main` in the output folder.